# How to Check if Page is Reloaded in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

I have made a simple to-do list app in which I am adding tasks which user is giving as input. The problem is when the user inputs the task and reloads the page previous task are retained. Like I deployed the app on Heroku and opened the app with different devices, So, If one user from one device enters a task it's saved and reflected to another user on another device also.

Therefore  I want to make some changes so that the `item` array gets cleared on page refresh. i.e whenever a user refreshes the page or another user opens the app on another device then a list of tasks is independent for them. (or input items are not permanently stored).

Something like this   if(page.reload()) item= [];

Is there any method so that I can clear my array on page refresh, below is my code in case someone wants to suggest any changes in logic.

Here's the Deployed Site: https://todo-list-tasks.herokuapp.com/

Thanks !!

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const date = require(__dirname + "/date.js");

const app = express();

app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.use(express.static("public"));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

let item = ["Do Meditation", "Complete Backlogs"];

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    let day = date();
    res.render("list", { kindOfDate: day, listitem: item });
})

app.post("/", function (req, res) {
    let newListItem = req.body.newItem;
    item.push(newListItem);
    res.redirect("/");
    // console.log(req.body.newItem);
})

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, function () {
    console.log("Server Started on Port 3000");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

since `"/ "` is the root and is called everytime when a site is reloaded, adding a line
`item = [] ;` inside `app.get("/")` can clear the array every time page is refreshed.
But I belive this might come with a side effect that if any user reloads the page `item array` will be cleared.

PS : when `app.get("/")` is called it means page is refreshed.

Comment: Yeah! I tried this but there's one problem that when the POST request is called `app.post("/")` then I am redirecting to home route `("/")` which means that every time user submits input `app.get("/")` is called. Thus implementing this will again and again clear the item array.

Comment: That means clearing array on reload won't work right ? either manual reload or redirect ?

Comment: try checking the status codes, redirect and get have different status codes right ?

Comment: and if reloading clears the array, any user reloading will clear list for everyone too right ?

Comment: Yeah that also a Problem, you pointed right. Can you please help me how can I make it independent for every user.

Comment: If you want to make it independent, you either have to store data in user's local storage or create a database and store data. in short you need a way to identify a user and store data for that specific user separately

Comment: Is there any way I can add a new task without reloading the Page? (Using Node) I have added the link to the deployed webpage in the description of the Question. Suggest me some method.

Comment: of course you do. Use ajax. You can use ajax to send the post request to update data and instead of redirecting in server side you can send your list as response to request, and use it to update ui